# Insert record to the table with primary key column only in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

As far as I know in SQL Server, I generally have 2 approaches to create an auto increment column (I am new to SQL Server, so, I am sorry if I am wrong):

1. Via sequence, and reference it during insert
2. Via marking this column with the `IDENTITY` keyword

In my case I have a table, which contains **only one** column - primary key, marked with `IDENTITY`, so you can assume something like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I know, that, in first aforementioned case, we can do the following, for example:

```
INSERT INTO sequence_table 
VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR sequence);
```

But my question is - is it possible, to achieve the same with the second approach.

What do I exactly mean: I have only the table `my_table` and that is all (weird use case, but this is how it is). In the application I need to generate a SQL `Insert` statement into this table.

**Also note:** sometimes the `id` column will be provided, sometimes it won't.

Appreciate any help

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default values`:

```
insert into my_table
    default values;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6829752b8233bbfe5875744de38fdd71) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That seems great! But I think, in order for this to work I need to set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF for my_table, right?

Comment: @misha2048 . . . No.  Did you look at the db<>fiddle?

Comment: Yes, but, if I set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON, then the following message is 
generated: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'my_table' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column. Am I doing something wrong? I just did the insert you provided, but with IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.

Comment: @misha2048 . . . I misunderstood your comment.  `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to **off* by default and it should be **off** for this operation as well.  This is no need to set it to on.